# Can't set voltage on GPU msm8953

Tags: android, c, kernel

I'm trying to overvolt the GPU adreno 506 in the snapdragon 625 processor, but i'm having troubles on setting the voltage

```
gfx_vreg_corner: ldo@0185f000 {
    compatible = "qcom,msm8953-gfx-ldo";
    reg = <0x0185f000 0x30>, <0xa4000 0x1000>;
    reg-names = "ldo_addr", "efuse_addr";

    regulator-name = "msm_gfx_ldo";
    regulator-min-microvolt = <1>;
    regulator-max-microvolt = <7>;

    qcom,ldo-voltage-ceiling = <620000 680000 750000>;
    qcom,ldo-voltage-floor =   <510000 510000 600000>;

    qcom,num-corners = <7>;
    qcom,num-ldo-corners = <3>;
    qcom,ldo-enable-corner-map = <1 1 1 0 0 0 0>;
    qcom,init-corner = <4>;

    vdd-cx-supply = <&pm8953_s2_level>;
    qcom,vdd-cx-corner-map = <RPM_SMD_REGULATOR_LEVEL_LOW_SVS>,
                <RPM_SMD_REGULATOR_LEVEL_LOW_SVS>,
                <RPM_SMD_REGULATOR_LEVEL_SVS>,
                <RPM_SMD_REGULATOR_LEVEL_SVS_PLUS>,
                <RPM_SMD_REGULATOR_LEVEL_NOM>,
                <RPM_SMD_REGULATOR_LEVEL_NOM_PLUS>,
                <RPM_SMD_REGULATOR_LEVEL_TURBO>;

    mem-acc-supply = <&gfx_mem_acc>;
    qcom,mem-acc-corner-map = <1 1 1 2 2 2 2>;
    qcom,ldo-init-voltage-adjustment = <35000 25000 0>;
```

This is the regulator that controls the clocks and voltage

```
        qcom,ldo-voltage-ceiling = <620000 680000 750000>;
    qcom,ldo-voltage-floor =   <510000 510000 600000>;

    qcom,num-corners = <7>;
    qcom,num-ldo-corners = <3>;
    qcom,ldo-enable-corner-map = <1 1 1 0 0 0 0>;
```

Editing this values should impact on the voltage being sent to the gpu,  but no matter what value I put here it will just ignore, although following  the voltage limit written in the manual:

```
#define MIN_LDO_VOLTAGE         375000
#define MAX_LDO_VOLTAGE         980000
```

**I know the risks of overvolting in smartphones, but I insist on finding a way to set a voltage, becouse the phone i'm using has really good thermal conduction**